# Laravel implode on array

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code:

```
$category = $product->category;
if(!empty($category->category_id)){
  $category = [$category->parent->title,$category->title];
}
```

it gives result such as:

```
Default Category first level category
```

what i want is to add `>` between `Default Category` and `first level category`

how do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use php's implode function like this `$category = implode(" > ", [$category->parent->title,$category->title]);`, then you will get your desired result.

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: in that case, problem is with your array($category), check it.

Comment: dd($category) = `"Default Category > first level category"
`

Comment: fixed, the issue was when i use implode i don't need to use foreach anymore.

Comment: last thing? how can i add links to each category name of my function?

Comment: you can store that value in another index like $category[$key]['links'] = implode(" > ", [$category->parent->title,$category->title]); Then when you need to show it anywhere, you can echo that index value